# log4net 1.2 RollingFileAppender not working

Tags: log4net, rollingfileappender

I'm using log4net v1.2 with a Windows Service App. My RollingFileAppender seems not to work. I'm pasting the logging sections of my service.exe.config below. Can anyone advise where I'm going wrong?

```xml
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
```

.....(lots of other config stuff)

```xml
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net" >
    <param name="File" value="D:\\Trinity\\Booking\\OneDay_PostTrade\\logs\\Trinity.log" />
    <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="20MB" />
    <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="10" />
    <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="ALL" />
    <param name="RollingStyle" value="Composite" />
    <param name="appendToFile" value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

...(stuff in between)

```xml
<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</root>
```

.....(stuff in between)

```xml
<logger name="CSFB.PostTradeRulesEngine">
    <level value="ALL"/>        
</logger>
```

Comment: Did you remember to initialize it in code?

Comment: if you mean 
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(PostTradeRules));
where PostTradeRules is my class name, then I did...:)

Answer (score 3):

The user your windows service is running as might not have write permission for the log file.
Another possibility is that you forgot to execute `XmlConfigurator.Configure();`

Comment: Jens, why exactly do I need to execute XmlConfigurator.Configure()? M asking because I genuinely dont have a clue. :)

Comment: One more note here Jens... i think m using an old version of VS which does not have XmlConfigurator. Can I use BasicConfigurator instead?

Comment: XmlConfigurator is a class of the log4net framework, has nothing to do with VS

Comment: oh ok...in that case, are you saying that i might be using an old version of the log4net.dll itself?

Comment: @Rishi, my bad, the XmlConfigurator was introduced in v. 1.2.9. If you´r using a earlier version this should do the trick: DOMConfigurator.Configure()

Answer (score 1):

try writing:

```
<log4net debug="true">
```

it will post all errors to console.

Comment: Hi Andrey, where do I put this bit?

Comment: @Rishi Poptani what about googling a bit? http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/example-apps.html don't be lazy

Comment: @Rishi Poptani what doesn't work? download and run samples from link. do they work? and about <log4net debug="true"> it will not solve your problem but it will output errors to console so that you can analyze and fix them

Answer (score 1):

thanks to everyone who responded. I dont know what i changed but my logging has started working fine.

Posting my logging sections. I didnt change anything in the code, except a line in the AssemblyInfo.cs:
[assembly: log4net.Config.Domain(UseDefaultDomain=true)]

Thanks again.:)